# Why are Music Services in Android never affected by doze mode?

Tags: android, android-service, foreground-service, android-wake-lock

Can anyone please explain to me at technical level, why does a music player's service run continuously after the screen is turned off. Why is it never affected by doze mode?  I want to create a service along similar lines, but it should perform a particular task every 20 seconds continuously.

I would be glad if anyone can explain this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: A task that runs every 20 seconds will very quickly drain the battery.

Comment: I know that but it is as per the business use case

Comment: what are the solutions if it's quickly drain the battery? make it longer than 20s is that true?

Answer (score 2):

The music player's service runs as a 'foreground service'.

Foreground services for the most part are unaffected by doze when used in combination with a partial wakelock:

[Purpose of WakeLock in modern Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53093127/purpose-of-wakelock-in-modern-android)

If your app needs to create a foreground service while the app is in the background:

```
ContextCompat.startForegroundService()
```

Inside the service, promote it to the foreground and post the notification by calling:

```
startForeground()
```

From the Android docs:
"A foreground service performs some operation that is noticeable to the user. For example, an audio app would use a foreground service to play an audio track. Foreground services must display a Notification. Foreground services continue running even when the user isn't interacting with the app."

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services

Typically, a music app will change the foreground service notification from a 'liability' that annoys the user to an asset by displaying an image of the artist, the current track and offer media buttons like play/pause/rewind/forward.

A foreground service should not generally be used to do regularly scheduled work because it will greatly reduce the device's battery life.

Instead, try to use `WorkManager`, `JobScheduler` or `Firebase Cloud Messaging` to wake the device up only when necessary.

[Execute frequent tasks using the Work Manager API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51202905/execute-task-every-second-using-work-manager-api)

But it will not be possible to "poll" or run your code every 20 seconds with these solutions. You really need to find a solution that works with "Doze" instead of fighting against it.

Comment: Good one but the chinese OEM's block the workmanager after some time and it does not run until the app is opened again.

Comment: Thanks Elletlar. I have tried foreground services with wakelock, but the app gets killed . A normal foreground service works, but the scheduled task gets suspended on screen off and starts again when screen is turned on. At present, I am using a foreground service with a timer task to run tasks at regular intervals.

Comment: This blog has some tips [Do not kill my app](https://dontkillmyapp.com/stock_android)